# PHP dynamic instanciating

Tags: php, oop

I've an object which returns a string and I would like instanciate another object with the string returned, why in PHP I can't instanciate this way ?

For Example:

```
// getController() returns a string name controller
$c = new $this->router->getController() ;


// I have to do this way:
$controller = $this->router->getController() ;
$c = new $controller() ;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: But you can! What error specifically do you receive from this code?

Comment: I do it like in your example all time, seems to be the easiest and most reliable way.

Comment: Oh, wait. I think I misunderstood the question. You want to do it directly, like $c = new {$this->router->getController()}; ?

Comment: This seems like the most clear method of doing this, though.

Comment: @Maxim Kumpan: Yes :)

Comment: @Haza: Sorry but it's not like my case.

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax thing.  I think I remember seeing an RFC to allow more dynamic class instantiation, but assigning to a variable first gets the job done, no?

Comment: Yeah, you did: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call.